# countdown timer, no refresh on page change

Tags: php, javascript

```
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

var time_left = 50;
var cinterval;
var timestatus=1;

function time_dec(){
    time_left--;
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = time_left;
    if(time_left == 0){
        clearInterval(cinterval);
    }
}

function resumetime()
{
    //time_left = 50;
    clearInterval(cinterval);
    cinterval = setInterval('time_dec()', 1000);
}

function defaultstart()
{
    time_left = 50;
    clearInterval(cinterval);
    cinterval = setInterval('time_dec()', 1000);
}

function stopstarttime()
{
    if(timestatus==1)
{
    clearInterval(cinterval);
    document.getElementById('stopbutton').value="Start";
    timestatus=0;
}
    else
{
    clearInterval(cinterval);
    cinterval = setInterval('time_dec()', 1000);
    document.getElementById('stopbutton').value="Stop";
    timestatus=1;
}
}

defaultstart();

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<body>
Redirecting In <span id="countdown">50</span>.
<INPUT TYPE="button" value="stop" id="stopbutton" onclick="stopstarttime()">
</body>
</HTML>
```

I am beginner. I have 10 questionnaire pages. Is there any possibility that this timer          do not refresh on page change/refresh. And it should work differently for different users. If possible please help me.

Comment: Not in JavaScript. You will have to use PHP and sessions to make it work between page refreshes.

Comment: What have you tried? Pasting code from a previous answer isn't going to help us solve your problem.

Comment: if you want to store in js then you need to use browser cache

Comment: You could have the questionnaire in an iframe and the timer outside - that way, timer won't get refreshed. But it's an old-worldy solution.

Comment: try to use javascript cookies.

Comment: Or even easier, upon starting the quiz, send one cookie with END time. Then all pages can open this cookie, calculate time till end, and show exact time remaining.

Comment: Sure it's posible in javascript, just load other pages using ajax (you will have one page with counter). Passing it to browser cache it's not good solution for several reasons (pages are loaded in difrent time, when you reopen page, you don't get new counter and more).

Comment: Ajax is the way to go here

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992669/countdown-timer-no-refresh-on-page-change, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191772/reach-some-specific-page-after-ending-countdown-timer

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Please tell me one thing more: Is it possible in this coding that on finishing the timer it redirects to some specific page automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the timestamp the timer should end in a cookie or localStorage. Then use this cookie to display the correct counter. This solution is not 100% safe (the user can alter the value of this cookie to make the counter last longer if they know how to alter cookies/localStorage via the developer console), so don't use it in situations where this is bad.

```
var timeLeft = 50;
if( window.localStorage ) {
  if( !localStorage.getItem( 'endTimer' ) ) {
    localStorage.setItem( 'endTimer', new Date().getTime() + (timeLeft * 1000) );
  }
}
```

The time in miliseconds left is then `localStorage.getItem( 'endTimer' ) - new Date().getTime()`.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Please tell me one thing more: Is it possible in this coding that on finishing the timer it redirects to some specific page automatically ?

Comment: set `location.href` to the url you want to redirect to.

Comment: Thanks  dear Sumurai8, Please tell me one thing more, where should I set location.href

Comment: and also tell me how can I convert it into minutes and hours

Comment: @Dr.Vivek getTime returns time in milliseconds.